# Start 2 files at once and closes one of them when one closes

Tags: windows-7, batch, code

I need code to make a batch file start 2 programs at once and when one program closes the other one closes as well. For example:

```
start program 1
start program 2 
When I exit program 1, program 2 will exit as well. But not before program 1 does.
```

I have already tried this code:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files\CCleaner"
start CCleaner64.exe

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wunderlist2"
start Wunderlist.exe
```

This one opens both programs at once, but when I exit "CCleaner," Wunderlist stays open.

Comment: alright actualy i need a hotkey code for an Application that toggles a certain key only when the application is running!

Answer (score 1):

You need to start program 2 without waiting, then start program 1 and wait for it to finish. Once complete you need to kill program 2.

Try this:

```
@echo off
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wunderlist2\Wunderlist.exe”
start /wait "C:\Program Files\CCleaner\CCleaner64.exe”
taskkill /f /im “Wunderlist.exe”
```

Comment: i don't want to 2nd application to close after the 1st one opens i want them to stay running at the same time and when program #1 closes program #2 closes as well something like 
start Prog 1 
start prog 2 
then when prog 1 closes prog 2 follows

Comment: @MaddoxX which is exactly what the script does.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what you can do. I've got to tell you, this is probably not the best method, but if I needed an quick fix, this is what I would do.

First, find the process id of both processes. Right?

Next, scan the list of processes running via grep or any similar command. Do it,say every one second.

Check if both IDs are still present. The moment your loop finds out one of the process is not found, kill the other one.

But yes, this means you'll have to keep another process with a loop running in the background which might slow your PC down, but not by a large amount.

Comment here if you do find a better idea

Comment: The idea will work, but your description of it is not very clear. In my opinion, this answer isn’t helpful at all. If you’ve got some examples of Windows based scripts to do this, then that would help. Otherwise, it is just confusing.

Comment: Right. I couldn't get access to a pc running Windows and so, couldn't give a script. I'll edit the answer as soon as I get my hands on a windows laptop

Comment: I don't believe you can do this with scripts.  In code the right approach would be to launch two threads, each waits on the process ID of one program and when the wait releases it kills the other process if it's still running.  While "running" it would be in a wait state using no CPU time at all.